# C++ Object as argument

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a program where I need to pass objects as argument to a function in a class, but it gives me these errors:

> ------ Build started: Project: C++ Program, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
>
> Main.cpp
> [...]\game.h(8): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Chapter'
> [...]\main.cpp(9): error C2660: 'Game::addChapter' : function does not take 1 arguments
>
> Game.cpp
> [...]\game.h(8): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Chapter'
> [...]\game.cpp(20): error C2511: 'void Game::addChapter(Chapter *)' :
>    overloaded member function not found in 'Game'
> [...]\game.h(3) : see declaration of 'Game'

My Code:

Main.cpp

```
#include "Game.h"
#include "Chapter.h"

int main(void)
{
Game game;
Chapter hi;

game.addChapter(&hi);
game.start();
return 0;
}
```

Game.cpp

```
#include "Game.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "Chapter.h"

using namespace std;

Game::Game()
{

}

Game::~Game()
{

}

void Game::addChapter(Chapter *chapter)
{
    cout << "Added";
}

void Game::start()
{
cout << "Started";
}
```

Game.h

```
#pragma once
class Game
{
public:
    Game();
    ~Game();

    void addChapter(Chapter *chapter);
    void start();
};
```

Chapter.cpp

```
#include "Chapter.h"

Chapter::Chapter()
{

}


Chapter::~Chapter()
{

}


void Chapter::getInput()
{
cout << "Hello";
}
```

Chapter.h

```
#pragma once
class Chapter
{
public:
    Chapter();
    ~Chapter();

protected:
    void getInput();
};
```

Why am I getting this error and how can I solve the problem?

Comment: I don't see where you tell us *exactly* what the error is and *what lines* it pertains to...

Comment: How is `Chapter` declared?

Comment: You forgot to include Chapter.h in Game.h. At the point that Game.h is compiled, the compiler has no idea what a `Chapter` is, and gives you an error.

Comment: @Cameron That should be an answer.

Comment: Why don't I need to do that with string for example?

Comment: @Erik: You're not using anything declared in `string`, but your question is still valid -- the reason is that `#include`s are expanded into the included file's full text by the preprocessor before the file is actually compiled. This means that a given .h file has the context of all the files that were included before it (even if it doesn't include those files itself). In this case, Chapter.h sees Game.h, `iostream`, `vector`, and `string` because main.cpp includes them before including Chapter.h. But don't rely on this, because another .cpp might include different things (or nothing!) first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include `Chapter.h` in `Game.h`.

```
\game.h(8): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Chapter
```

You need to tell where the compiler can find the definition of `Chapter` when it reads the definition of addChapter in `Game.h`.

Comment: You could also forward declare Chapter in this case since the object size is not needed just to point to it.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a include to Chapter.h inside of Game.h

```
#include "Chapter.h"

#pragma once
class Game
{
public:
    Game();
    ~Game();

    void addChapter(Chapter *chapter);
    void start();
};
```

With that everything works like you'd expect